# How to make one div's height depended of another div's height?

Tags: html, css, height

Well I have such simple divs structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="1" class="block">
    1            
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="block">
    2
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdMrs/14/)

Content of `#1` can dynamically changed by javascript and its height can be changed depended of content. What I want is to make `#2` the same height as `#1`. I understand that I can use javascript for this purpose but I suggest there must be some not such tricky way to make those divs' heights equal using only CSS and/or changing divs' positioning some how.

Comment: No, not semantically. What you want is faux columns, and there's a bunch of techniques here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it unless your data is tabular, but have you considered using tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you can't do it semantically. You have to use a little trick to fake the 100% height. It's called faux columns, and you can read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/).

In your case, we can fake it by adding a few background divs:

```
<div class="background bg1"></div>
<div class="background bg2"></div>
```

Then changing your CSS like so:

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bg1 {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.bg2 {
    left: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}​
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdMrs/18/).

Comment: And flexbox is supposedly the future, someday. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks a lot... It's kind'a strange that such simple thing has to be done such tricky way...

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I hadn't seen that. Looks very promising, should have been part of the spec when we decided to kill table-based design :p

Comment: Nice. It's a shame that we STILL have to go to this much trouble for what you'd think would be simple functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery Way: Use .height() to return the height of Div1 and then simply use .css() to set Div2 to Div1's height. When div one changes, you can use the resize event to trigger a function that would change div2's height.

The CSS way: Christian Varga's answer seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Question specifies _only css_ though :p

Comment: Adding a way to do this via css to my answer.

Comment: Haha but `height: inherit` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It made sense when I was thinking about it :p, upped your answer :)

Comment: Yeah I find it really weird how it just can't be done semantically. Your idea, or `height: 100%`, should, in theory, work. But they don't work as expected. I don't like the faux column technique, but short of using tables or javascript there's nothing else we can do!