# Making overlaying divs equal using css

Tags: html, css

I have one div overlaying another div as follows:

```
div.container { 
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    background:url('http://www.scratchprogramming.org/img/book.png');   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    background-position: 62% 70%; 
    overflow:hidden; 
} 

div.content { 
    position: absolute; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width:100%; 
    z-index:10; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

My html starts out like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="catImage">
        <img src="img/Scratchcat.png" alt="cat" />
    </p>
</div><!--container-->  
<div  class="content">
```

Now I had to set the height on the cat image really long so that the background image in the container (`book.png`) will fill the content area.

The problem is when testing on different browsers... somtimes the `book.png` background goes over the content length, leaving a couple of inches extra on the bottom.

Is there any way I can make the content and container height the same using css and not having to play around with the image height ?

Here is the working example: http://www.scratchprogramming.org

Comment: Try adding a style for html,body height and set it to 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/cB6kn/

Comment: It is not very clear what you're trying to do. You don't want the height of `.container` to exceed `.content`, is that right?

Comment: If i set the cat image height to normal then I only see half of the background image (book). Currently it is set to a height of 735px. I only set the height longer to make the background stretch to the accordion(content length). I basically want the content and the background image to be of equal height, using css. The accordion has to be on top .

Comment: Thans joe, I tried your solution without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution very similar to this:

[How to make one div's height depended of another div's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895379/how-to-make-one-divs-height-depended-of-another-divs-height)

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body { 
  background: url('http://www.scratchprogramming.org/img/book.png') no-repeat center center fixed;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://www.scratchprogramming.org/img/book.png', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://www.scratchprogramming.org/img/book.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could improve your answer by putting 4 spaces before your lines of code to make it a code block (which makes it more readable). It's also never a bad idea to explain what the asker was doing wrong.